# Why does adding a class with Angular seem to affect positioning

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having a very strange bug when adding a class to a ui-router element. An absolutely positioned element that spans the entire view snaps to the width of its parent when the active class is added.

I have recreated the bug in a plunker found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hh76ldAI6cyPNZmeDNuI?p=preview)

My code looks as such:

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <header>
      <span ng-click="toggleNav()">☰</span>
    </header>
    <nav ng-class="{active: navOpen}">
      <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="container" ui-view ng-class="{active: navOpen}"></section>
</body>
```

**style.scss**

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  background: gold;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  transition: all .5s linear;
  &.active {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
  transition: all .5s linear;
  &.active {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  div {
    @extend header;
    height: auto;
    top: 25px;
    background: deepskyblue;
    padding: 10px;
    section {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      span:last-child {
        float: right;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**app.coffee**

```
app = angular.module 'plunker', ['ui.router']

app.config ($stateProvider) ->
    $stateProvider
      .state 'foo',
        url: ''
        templateUrl: 'foo.html'

app.controller 'MainCtrl', ($scope) ->
  $scope.navOpen = false

  $scope.toggleNav = ->
    $scope.navOpen = !$scope.navOpen
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Solved: changed the width and auto margin to a 5% left and right padding**

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the body:

```
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Get rid of `width: 90%` on the container:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}
```

Comment: I need the width on the container.. That is something I can't drop, but thanks for your input.

Comment: The width is the reason it's doing the jumping. And why didn't you state that in question? @camwhite

Comment: Updated to reflect that. Thank you!

Comment: Does the width have to be 90%? @camwhite

Answer (score 0):

Personally I try to avoid using position:absolute. It masks the behaviour of the elements in your page. In this case it makes it harder to see that .ng-scope adds a margin to your body element. Remove with: 100%; and you'll see that the weird extra space is being added on both sides.

You can solve it by overriding the ng-scope class. Add

.ng-scope { margin:0; }

to the bottom of your style.css